# C2call sdk Integration in Phonegap application

Tags: cordova, ios6, ios7

I have seen that C2call is providing sdk for both android and iOS app development with SDK Integration.

I want to develope a Hybrid Application for mobile using Phonegap with skills Html5,Css3,javaScript,Jquery,jqueryMobile.
In my application i want to integrate C2call sdk for Chat functionality (like ex:whatsApp,skype).

i want to know wheather C2Call sdk will support phonegap application.Is it possible to use C2call methods for implementing chat functionality without using C2call views and having only html5 UI.

Is there any user have done this before.So, please reply valuable suggestions with references of possibilties to succeed in Integration of sdk in phonegap.

thanks 
Suresh